# How to use js function from imported npm package in angular 4

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm using angular 4, here is the problem I have proposal-list component, and I would like to use accounting-js from [npmjs for accounting-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/accounting-js) and [link documentation how to use the function](http://nashdot.github.io/accounting-js/docs/), I installed using

```
npm install accounting-js
```

here is my proposal-list.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { formatNumber } from 'accounting-js/lib/formatNumber.js';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-proposal-list',
  templateUrl: './proposal-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./proposal-list.component.css']
})
export class ProposalListComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

my question how I can use the function inside formatNumber.js?

I tried to use in proposal-list.component.html

```
total money =   {{formatNumber(1000500.65)}}
```

but it's not showed up, but no error message.

#### addional info for problem

here is my app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomepageComponent } from './homepage/homepage.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { DocumentsComponent } from './documents/documents.component';
import { ProposalListComponent } from './proposal/proposal-list/proposal-list.component';
import { ProposalShowComponent } from './proposal/proposal-show/proposal-show.component';
import { ProposalNewComponent } from './proposal/proposal-new/proposal-new.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomepageComponent,
    DocumentsComponent,
    ProposalListComponent,
    ProposalShowComponent,
    ProposalNewComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    AlertModule.forRoot(),
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be doing it in your ts file and if you want to do it in your html then you have to define a function in your ts. Try this.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { formatNumber } from 'accounting-js/lib/formatNumber.js';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-proposal-list',
  templateUrl: './proposal-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./proposal-list.component.css']
})
export class ProposalListComponent implements OnInit {
private money: number ;
      constructor() { }
      ngOnInit() {
this.money = formatNumber(1000500.65)
      }
    }
```

and in your html

> total money =   {{money}}

but if you want to use it on the fly, you can create a custom pipe using FormatNumber function

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

import { formatNumber } from 'accounting-js/lib/formatNumber.js';

@Pipe({name: 'formatNumber'})
export class FormatNumberPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(money:number): number {
        return formatNumber(money)
    }
}
```

and can use it like

```
total money =   1000500.65 | formatNumber
```

**Update**
You must include your pipe in the declarations array of the AppModule.

> app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormatNumberPipe} from './pipe.component';// whatever the name of your pipe component

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        FormatNumberPipe// **<-- this guy**
    ]

......
```

Comment: he is using it in his ts file of the component. can you clarify your answer what you want to say.

Comment: formatNumber function, he is using in component.html using interpolation. He can't use it unless it is defined in component.ts file. importing alone doesn't help!

Comment: but in nginit he did this `this.money = formatNumber(1000500.65)`

Comment: @JayDeeEss thanks for your answer, I'm interesting using pipe, but I get an error in my view Error: Template parse errors: The pipe 'formatNumber' could not be found

Comment: make sure you define your pipe in declarations array in your app.module.ts

Comment: Got it now! my bad. confisued with question and answer ;)

Comment: @JayDeeEss I just upload app.module.ts, how I define  pipe in declarations array (sorry still new in angular)

Comment: check my update.... check this if still not clear https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes

Comment: I consider this answer correct, although my test still not work, the problem is not from importing pipe but the module it self (js), I'll post in another question, thank you for all help

Answer (score 0):

if the import is a problem then you need to think about these below stuffs.

- wat is the export type of the function in side your js file like UMD, AMD, es2015, etc
- then you need to understand which types of module is imported in which way in typescript.
- once you imported the module/function you can then call them from your typescript

like you can import open function `import * as services from 'thisService'`
But if that function is inside a module, you need to import it from the module like `imort { service} from 'thisServiceModule'`.

Hope it helps