# How create custom pipe in angular 4 with some resources to format number (accounting.js)

Tags: angular

here is the problem (my background is rails and I'm still learning angular 4)

I have accounting javascript file (.js) ([accounting.js](http://openexchangerates.github.io/accounting.js/)) which has function **accounting.formatNumber()** that I would like to use in angular.
I did some search I found [npmjs package for this js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/accounting-js) and installed with **npm install accounting-js**, I also found [accounting.d.ts](https://github.com/slavovojacek/adbrain-typescript-definitions/blob/master/accounting/accounting.d.ts). now the question, consider resources above how I create custom pipe to use this function.

here the result that I would like to achieve, using function in my html view (for example I have proposal-list.component.html) and I would like {{ 123456.78 | formatNumber }} will print to screen 123,456.78

I did post a [question previously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46179591/938947)  and someone give me a clue to [custom pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes), I did test to use js directly but still no luck(see code below)

proposal-list.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { formatNumber } from 'accounting-js/lib/formatNumber.js';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-proposal-list',
  templateUrl: './proposal-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./proposal-list.component.css']
})
export class ProposalListComponent implements OnInit {
  totalMoney: number = 0;
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.totalMoney = formatNumber(123456.78)
  }
}
```

proposal-list.component.html

```
<p>test = {{ totalMoney }}</p>
```

it's showing label test without value,

Comment: you got an answer in the question you posted, what's wrong with it?

Comment: I put a checkmark because of clues for my problem( newbie for angular just know about custom pipe) but I still not solved my problem, if you checked from links that I passed above some guys referenced if there is file with d.ts (accounting.d.ts) I can use it with custom pipe, but I don't know how to create custom pipe from that file.

Comment: so what exactly is your problem now?

Comment: how to use https://github.com/slavovojacek/adbrain-typescript-definitions/blob/master/accounting/accounting.d.ts in angular and if possible customize it to custom pipe so I can use {{  123456.78 | formatNumber }} will showing 123.456,78

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing a similar problem of number transformation according to culture so I had written a custom pipe using  [ECMAScript Intl API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat)

The code is basically like this :

```
     import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

  @Pipe({
  name: 'numberLocale'
})
export class NumberLocalePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, selectedCulture: any): any {

    if (!value) {
      return;
    }
    var userLang = navigator.language;
    if (selectedCulture) {
      return new Intl.NumberFormat(selectedCulture).format(value);
    } else {
      return new Intl.NumberFormat(userLang).format(value);
    }

  }

}
```

Here I am using the `Intl.NumberFormat` of ECMAScript you can use your `account.js` nothing much changes.

The whole code you can see in this [working Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/p0WI56Z3xxPa2AtrSKPx?p=preview)  I created for you.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

At first generate new pipe using angular-cli with command: `ng g pipe format-number` then:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'formatNumber'})
export class FormatNumberPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number): number {
    // there You should write your formula for transforming numbers into string like: 123456.78 into 123,456.78
  }
}
```

Comment: I did this and still not work, also from your sample above not includes any resources that I mentioned (js or t.ds ), thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

There is a default currency pipe which does this for you.

https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe

If you don't want to use that then go with javascript

```
<p>test = {{ totalMoney.toLocaleString() }}</p>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

Comment: thank you for info, I have take a look that before, my country using different format (IDR) and that currencypipe is not showing Rp. code, thousand separator and comma is also different,